# Electric 220 be stove. G,E

Tags: stove

have a 3wire 220 stove , one wire white,one red ,one black .Now on the breaker at power panel where does the red wire go?

Comment: Can you post photos of your situation please?

Answer (score 2):

A 220V appliance with 3 wires, red, black, and white is configured to have TWO hot wires (RED and BLACK) and one NEUTRAL (WHITE).  In most cases today you also have a ground (GREEN) connection.  Check the manual for the unit to be sure what needs to be hooked up.

So in the panel you must hook this up to a single 220V circuit breaker.  The red and the black wire go to the two terminals on that breaker.  The white wire goes to the neutral bus bar.  The green should go to the ground bus bar.

Please consider hiring a qualified electrician for this installation as your question is so basic that I'm concerned that you may not have enough experience to connect this appliance safely.

Answer (score 2):

Any stove or dryer can be wired up 3-wire *or* 4-wire, so there's no such thing as a 3-wire stove.  That becomes a 4-wire stove if you move 1 jumper wire; just download the stove's instructions and follow them.

If you are running new cable, **you are required to use a 4-wire connection**.

Installing a 3-wire connection has been illegal since 1989. And for darn good reason: if there's any trouble on the white wire, it ***will*** electrify the chassis of the stove.

Wiring it up 4-wire is mandatory! Not only will you get written up if caught, but your insurance won't pay if someone is hurt.

If you are able to connect the ground wire and remove the neutral-ground jumper as instructed, then  you can use a plain $10 240V breaker, and red and black go on the 2 terminals.  If you don't see 2 terminals, then you have the wrong breaker.  If it has 2 terminals *but the 2 handles move independently* that's the wrong breaker.

---

Now, if it's impossible to wire it up 4-wire because you cut off the ground wires or used really old cable or something, you have one more play: Fit a 2-pole GFCI breaker and put some stickers on the outlet.  This will make it safe and legal. However the breaker is $80.

The GFCI breaker will have 3 terminals for black, white and red.